# alignment and numbering of math formulas

Tags: equations, amsmath, align

I have 3 formulas which should be aligned at the = sign and numbered (1) to (3).

Seems a simple task but trying both \being{equation} with \begin{split} and \being{align} did not work out. I alwasy struggled with the numbering or wit the alignment. Never got it right.

For example my simple equations good look like:

```
a = x  + y     (1)

b = z - k      (2)

c = j x (z-k)  (3)
  = j x b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is specialised numbering and spacing as requested in the comments:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a &= x + y \tag{1}\\[2ex]
  b &= z - k \tag{2}\\[2ex]
  c &= j x (z-k) \tag{3}\\
    &= j x b \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

You can change the value `2ex` to increase or decrease the spacing.

To get equation numbers on the right instead of the left, use the `reqno` option to the documentclass `amsart` (or to the package `amsmath` if you are not using an ams class).

Comment: Yes, that is how I want it! thanks a lot. I also edited my original post to show you how it should really look like.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{align}
 a &= x  + y \\
 b &= z - k \\
 c &= j x (z-k) \\
   &= j x b \notag
 \end{align}
```

That's how I've always done it and it works for me.

Comment: well, but then = j + b gets it's own number which i think is wrong. also as this is part of my 7th chapter is numbers it as (7.1) to (7.4) but I want just (1) to (4). Also is it possible to add a empty line between each formula without adding another numbering tag. Because if I change \\ to \\\\ it numbers the empty line as well

Comment: Yeah spotted the last \\ as well

Comment: You also need a `\notag` on the last line to remove the number.

Comment: Updated my answer to show your suggestions.